# Is the curl of this electric field zero and is ampere law true?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, antennas

let's consider this couple of endless conductive cones connected to an AC voltage source:
[image]

As shown in the picture, it generates an electric field on circumferences along $\theta$, and a magnetic field on circumferences along $\phi$. Solving Maxwell equations, we get their expressions (which describe a TEM spherical waves):

$H_{\phi}(r,\vartheta)=\frac{H_{0}e^{-jkr}}{rsin\vartheta}$

$E_{\vartheta}(r,\vartheta)=\eta H_{\phi}(r,\vartheta),\,\,with\,\,\eta=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\varepsilon_{c}}}$

These fields have been used (see reference if you want, but my question is quite simple) to evaluate voltage (between two points of the two cones) and current (on one of the two cones) in this way:

$V(r) = \int_{\frac{\vartheta_{0}}{2}}^{\pi-\frac{\vartheta_{0}}{2}}E_{\vartheta}\underline{\vartheta}_{0}\cdot rd\vartheta\underline{\vartheta}_{0}$

$I(r)=\int_{C(r)}\underline{H}\cdot d\underline{c}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\underline{H}\cdot d\underline{c}$

where $\theta_0$ is supposed to be the angle of both cones (supposed to be equal in this case).

So, you may see that the laws of magnetostatics are used:

1. voltage is calculated as if curl of E were zero. But there is a changing magnetic field...and the electric field rotates, so how can its curl be zero?
2. current is calculated as if ampere law were true, without displacement current. But there is a changing electric field, so how can ampere law be true?

Reference: [here](https://slideplayer.com/slide/17821941/), page 8.

Comment: $V(r)$ and $I(r)$ are computed *on the cone* where there is no induction or displacement current (or at least both are negligible).  $\vec\nabla\times \vec E\ne 0$ in the region that is not the antenna.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero so near the antenna will E be on straight lines (curl =0)?

Comment: No... "near" the antenna the field will propagate through induction and displacement current but *on* the antenna (on the conductor) the displacement current is dwarfed by the conduction current.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ok, the logic is clear. But, what I don't understand is why the expressions of far fields are used, instead of near fields. Moreover, I was thinking that the vector magnetic potential is along r on the antenna. So, it's orthogonal to the path for voltage evaluation. May this be the cause of curl of E being zero on the antenna?

Comment: There’s no far field or near field on the antenna.